# Creating a path shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

This may seem like a simple question but I was wondering if you can create an easily accessible shortcut to a program file instead of having to navigate through C every time.

Comment: Right-click it and select "Create Shortcut", put shortcut where you want it.

Comment: Im talking about the address its self, if i right click it only gives me options to copy the whole path

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear.

Comment: It honestly couldnt be more clear lol

Comment: @DaveDiienno - Yes;  It could.  For instance are you asking how to create a shortcut to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on an application, select Send to:, and choose a destination for the shortcut.

Comment: Could i do that for a whole path though, i want to be able to create a shortcut that opens the whole path of something like programfiles(86)

Comment: Yes, you can do it for a folder.